# Unable to build IOS app on physical device

Tags: ios, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRK8w.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MykEA.jpg)

Able to run on ios simulator but unable run on real device,
I have tried cleaning the build, updating the cocoapods still facing issue for real devices

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. [Edit] the question and copy-paste the output to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

On XCode, Runner -> Targets -> Runner -> Build Phases -> Run Script -> Check 'For install builds only'

Comment: I did tried that also still failed